# How to combine Vigenère cipher with fibonacci

Tags: java, vigenere

I have Vigenère cipher java code, and it's running well, but i want to modify this code with fibonacci formula, so the encryption result like a one time pad method..
here is the code :

```
public class Coba {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String key = "abcd";
String ori = "satusatu";
String enc = enkripsibaru(ori, key);
System.out.println(enc);
System.out.println(key);
System.out.println(ori);
System.out.println(dekripsibaru(enc, key));
}
static String enkripsibaru (String plaintext, String key)
    {
        String s = "";
        int lengthPlainText = plaintext.length();
        int lengthKey = key.length();
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthPlainText; i++)
        {
            if (j >= lengthKey)
            {
            key = plaintext;
            lengthKey = lengthPlainText;
            j = 0;
            }

        s += (char) (((int) plaintext.charAt(i) + key.charAt(j))%26);
        j++;
        }
        return s;
    }   
    public static String dekripsibaru(String cipher, String kunci)
        {
            String s = "";
            int lengthCipherText = cipher.length();
            int lengthKey = kunci.length();
            int j = 0;
            int temp1;
            int a = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i<lengthCipherText; i++)
            {
            if (j >= lengthKey) 
            {
                temp1 = (int) cipher.charAt(i) - (int) s.charAt(a);
                if (temp1 < 0) {
                    temp1 += 26;
                }
            s += (char) (temp1 % 26);
            a++;
            }
            else
            {
            temp1 = (int) cipher.charAt(i) - (int)  kunci.charAt(j);
                if (temp1 < 0)
                {
                    temp1 += 26;
                }
                s += (char) (temp1 % 26);
            }
            j++;
            }
            return s;
        }

    }
```

what should i do with this code to combine with fibonacci?
thanks

Comment: So where's your code and what problem do you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to use the Fibonacci sequence instead of the key.

The Fibonacci sequence goes like follows:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, etc.

So the shifts of the respective letters would be the above, modulo 26:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 8, 3, etc.

So let's make a method to calculate the Fibonacci sequence:

```
static long fibonacci (int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    else return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

Now we replace:

```
s += (char) (((int) plaintext.charAt(i) + key.charAt(j))%26);
```

with:

```
s += (char) ((int) ((int) plaintext.charAt(i) + fibonacci(i)) % 26);
```

Comment: thank you Mr @Benito
but, where do i put the method to calculate fibonacci?

Comment: Anywhere inside your class. Note: it would be better to calculate the sequence in the for loop, instead of using recursion in this case. I'm just giving you a general idea of how to make this work.